# Is it possible to specialize a template using a member enum?

Tags: c++, templates, enums, template-specialization

```
struct Bar {
  enum { Special = 4 };
};

template<class T, int K> struct Foo {};
template<class T> struct Foo<T,T::Special> {};
```

Usage:

```
Foo<Bar> aa;
```

fails to compile using gcc 4.1.2
It complains about the usage of `T::Special` for partial specilization of Foo. If `Special` was a class the solution would be to a typename in front of it. Is there something equivalent to it for enums (or integers)?

Comment: If you replace T::Special with a concrete integer (99, say), it still doesn't compile under g++ 4.4.0: 'wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)'.I realise this is a separate issue, but shouldn't the compiler accept this?

Answer (score 16):

Since that is not allowed by C++ as [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543720/template-specilization-using-member-enums/4543783#4543783) by Prasoon, so an alternative solution would be to use `EnumToType` class template,

```
struct Bar {
  enum { Special = 4 };
};

template<int e>
struct EnumToType
{
  static const int value = e;
};

template<class T, class K> //note I changed from "int K" to "class K"
struct Foo
{};

template<class T> 
struct Foo<T, EnumToType<(int)T::Special> > 
{
   static const int enumValue = T::Special;
};
```

Sample code at ideone : http://www.ideone.com/JPvZy

---

Or, you can simply specialize like this (if it solves your problem),

```
template<class T> struct Foo<T,Bar::Special> {};

//usage
Foo<Bar, Bar::Special> f;
```

Comment: Note that you can use `enum` inside `EnumToType` instead of `static const int`. Also, the standard (C++0x, Boost) name for `EnumToType` is `integral_constant`.

Answer (score 8):

The type of a non-type template argument cannot depend on a template parameter of a partial specialization.

ISO C++03 14.5.4/9 says

> A partially specialized non-type argument expression shall not involve a template parameter of the partial specialization except when the argument expression is a simple identifier.

```
template <int I, int J> struct A {};
template <int I> struct A<I+5, I*2> {}; //error
template <int I, int J> struct B {};
template <int I> struct B<I, I> {};     //OK
```

So something like this is illegal `template<class T> struct Foo<T,T::Special> {};` because `T::Special` depends on `T`

The usage is also illegal. You have provided one template argument but you need to provide two.

Comment: Why does the type of the non-type template parameter depend on the template parameter of the partial specialization here?  The type is still `int`, no?

Comment: I am talking about the template argument (not about the template parameter `int K`) `T::Special` which depends on `T`.

Comment: Ah.  The type of the argument is dependent upon `T`, the type of the parameter is `int`.

Comment: @James :Added relevant text from the Standard :)

Comment: Can you please explain what does it mean by : "**A partially specialized** non-type argument expression" 0_o. Arguments expression can be partially specialized? how?, Thanks a lot :)