# Overloading a templated member function through enum

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Suppose I have an `EventHandle` class which is uniquely enumed by `READ`, `WRITE`, and `SIGNAL`, and I am implementing a member template which should return different data type with respect to different enums.

```
enum class EventType {
  READ,
  WRITE,
  SIGNAL
};

class EventHandle {

public:

  template <EventType type, typename = enable_if_t<is_same<type, READ>::value>>
  ReadEventHandle* cast () { return static_cast<ReadEventHandle>(this); }

  template <EventType type, typename = enable_if_t<is_same<type, WRITE>::value>>
  WriteEventHandle* cast () { return static_cast<WriteEventHandle>(this); }

  template <EventType type, typename = enable_if_t<is_same<type, SIGNAL>::value>>
  SignalEventHandle* cast () { return static_cast<SignalEventHandle>(this); }
};
```

And I have three derived classes from `EventHandle`.

```
class ReadEventHandle : public EventHandle {...}
class WriteEventHandle : public EventHandle {...}
class SignalEventHandle : public EventHandle {...}
```

Apprently what I wrote doesn't compile. Is there any way to achieve this type cast overload on "compile" time (e.g., no switch on enum)?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4543880/598696

Comment: why do you need this `EventHandler` and this enum type. It seems to be completly useless taking into account that you have 3 classes - why do you need to "cast".....

Comment: Please post the compiler errors you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative with some traits and specialization:

```
enum class EventType {
  READ,
  WRITE,
  SIGNAL
};

class ReadEventHandle;
class WriteEventHandle;
class SignalEventHandle;

template <EventType E> struct EventHandleType;

template <> struct EventHandleType<EventType::READ> { using type = ReadEventHandle; };
template <> struct EventHandleType<EventType::WRITE> { using type = WriteEventHandle; };
template <> struct EventHandleType<EventType::SIGNAL> { using type = SignalEventHandle; };
```

And then:

```
class EventHandle {
public:

  template <EventType E>
  typename EventHandleType<E>::type* cast();
};

template <EventType E>
typename EventHandleType<E>::type*
EventHandle::cast() { return static_cast<typename EventHandleType<E>::type*>(this); }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db423db93b0222fe)

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I fully understand what you are trying to do, but you certainly are not using SFINAE correctly. Here is compilable code which I hope could serve as guidance:

```
#include <type_traits>

enum class EventType {
  READ,
  WRITE,
  SIGNAL
};

class ReadEventHandle { };
class WriteEventHandle { };
class SignalEventHandle { };

ReadEventHandle re;
WriteEventHandle we;
SignalEventHandle se;

class EventHandle {

public:

  template <EventType type,  std::enable_if_t<type == EventType::READ>* = nullptr >
  ReadEventHandle* cast () { return &re; }

  template <EventType type, std::enable_if_t<type == EventType::WRITE>* = nullptr >
  WriteEventHandle* cast () { return &we; }

  template <EventType type, std::enable_if_t<type == EventType::SIGNAL>* = nullptr>
  SignalEventHandle* cast () { return &se; }
};

void* check() {
  return EventHandle().cast<EventType::READ>(); // Depending on cast argument, different pointers returned
}
```

Comment: Hi SergeyA, Thank you for the kind reply! This is exactly what I want! Could you please elaborate more on why your enable_if_t is actually working? Does it actually return a void type if the type matches?

Comment: @Jes, this is the essence of `enable_if`. When the condition is true, it has a type in it (which by default is `void`, but you can set it to something else in second argument to `enable_if`). When condition is false, there is no `type` member in it, and you have a substitution failure. `enable_if_t` is simply a template alias, which is the same thing as `typename std::enable_if<>::type` - but a very useful shorthand.